# TTS Speech Engine

Tags: java, android, text-to-speech

I have an activity that successfully implements the text to speech. However, when the resulting click on activity one, goes to activity 2, the speech engine ceases to work. I instantiated it a second time in the second activity, but it does not take the new instance. The second activity extends the first class and I am not sure if that is what is messing up everything. I have implemented the text to speech in another activity and it works fine. The only thing with this one is that the second class extends the first. Hope this is clear.

First activity works fine:

```
public class Traveling extends AppCompatActivity implements     TextToSpeech.OnInitListener
{
VoiceInstructionEnabler voiceinstructions;
TextToSpeech tts;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_choking);

    voiceinstructions=new VoiceInstructionEnabler(this);
    tts= new TextToSpeech(this,this);

    voiceinstructions.speakOut(speaktext, tts);
```

Second activity that gets called from the first

```
 public class Traveling_Instructions extends Traveling implements TextToSpeech.OnInitListener{

ListView instruction;
ArrayList<Traveling_Instructions> instructions= new ArrayList<Traveling_Instructions>();
VoiceInstructionEnabler vinstructions;
TextToSpeech tts;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    vinstructions=new VoiceInstructionEnabler(this);
    tts=new TextToSpeech(this,this);

    vinstructions.speakOut(speaktext, tts);
```

VoiceEnabler Class

```
  public class VoiceInstructionEnabler extends Activity implements   RecognitionListener,TextToSpeech.OnInitListener

{
 private TextToSpeech tts;

@Override
public void onInit(int status) {
     String sampletext="";
    if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {

        int result = tts.setLanguage(Locale.US);

        if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA
                || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
            Log.e("TTS", "This Language is not supported");
        } else {
            speakOut(sampletext,tts);
        }


    } else {
        Log.e("TTS", "Initialization Failed!");

    }


}

 @Override
//@TargetApi(15)
public void onDestroy() {
    // Don't forget to shutdown tts!
    if (tts != null) {
        tts.stop();
        tts.shutdown();
    }
    super.onDestroy();
}


public void speakOut(String text_to_speak,TextToSpeech tts) {

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        tts.speak(text_to_speak, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null, null);

    }
    else {

       tts.speak(text_to_speak, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);


    }
}
```

Comment: This is one case where the design style `one Activity, many Fragments` would help a lot.

Comment: Any other ideas with working with what I have now?

Comment: No. The only other idea I have is **disgusting** (replicating the TTS code for all the Activities which have to use it).

Comment: Do you think the fact that the one class extends the other is an issue? I am able to use the same code inn another activity and it works fine